# Difference between dataTask and uploadTask in NSURLSession

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsurlsession

In NSURLSession, we can use POST method to send data to server using NSURLSessionDataTask and NSURLSessionUploadTask. What is the difference between the two?

Comment: Not a huge amount - basically the upload task is a data task with an interface designed to make creating an upload more simple, according to [the docs for NSURLSessionUploadTask](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionUploadTask_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSURLSessionUploadTask)

Answer (score 3):

Big difference is that you can't use NSURLSessionDataTask to upload in the background. You need to use NSURLSessionUploadTask for that.

```
Unlike data tasks, you can use upload tasks to upload content in the background. (For details, see URL Session Programming Guide.)
```